# Are roller coasters proper names?

Tags: names, proper-nouns

I want to write a sentence like this:
I look up at the new roller coaster they built called Superman.

Superman is the name of the roller coaster. Do I need to do anything special with the name? for example should it be in italics?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should treat it as as a geographical name or business name: capitalize but not italicize or quote.

Comment: There are lots of articles which support this, e.g. [BBC Newsround](https://www.bbc.co.uk/newsround/48430614), [CNN Travel](https://edition.cnn.com/travel/article/scariest-roller-coaster-drops-world/index.html).

Answer (score -2):

Capitalize it, as it's a proper noun.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -3):

Make sure you dont put THE infront of the name as that will make you look dumb (trust me a lot of people make this mistake im not trying to insult you.) Capitalize it but don't italizise it or whatever, just capitalize them and you should be good.

-From a roller coaster enthusiast.

Comment: You need to cite sources for the information you supply in an answer. And, you should proof read better.